# Find the solution of the differential equations $p^2-y^2=0$ and $(p+1)^3=27(x+y)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the differential equations :

i) $p^2-y^2=0$

ii) $(p+1)^3=27(x+y)^2$

These questions in (non linear ordinary differential equations - can be solve in y)

My answer:

For (i)

$p^2=y^2$

$p=y$

${dp\over dx}={dy\over dx}$

And we know [$p={dy\over dx}$]

So

${dp\over dx}=p$

$\ln p=x+\ln c$

$p=ce^x$

By delet $p$ from :

$y=p$ and $p=ce^x$

We get :

$y=ce^x$

True ?

---

And for (ii)

$(p+1)^3=27(x+y)^2$

$3(p+1)^2 {dp\over dx}=54(x+y+x{dy\over dx}+y{dy\over dx})$

$3(p+1)^2 {dp\over dx}=54(x+y+xp+yp)$

$3(p+1)^2 {dp\over dx}=54(x(p+1)+y(p+1))$

${dp\over dx}={18(x+y)(p+1)\over (p+1)^2}$

${dp\over dx}={18(x+y)\over (p+1)}$

Is it true? And how can I complete ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused about your notation.  At first I thought that you were using $p$ for $y^{\prime}.$  But you use both $dy/dx$ and $dp/dx$, which makes me think that $p =dy/dx$ only by condition, not by definition.  I can't decipher your question.

Comment: Yes. $p={dy\over dx}=y^{\prime}$ , I don't use it for $dp\over dx$ ? And ${dy\over dx}=p$ by definition, not condition in this problem.

Comment: I edited the question, can you help me now?

Comment: You can check by differentiation that your solution to $1$ doesn't work. You might want to make it explicit from the beginning that $p = y'$ so others don't get confused.

Comment: Oh , so can you write the correct answer ?

Comment: Re (i), note that $$y'=\tfrac12\pm\sqrt{y^2+\tfrac14}$$ Can you finish? Re (ii), note that $$(y'+1)^2y''=18(x+y)(1+y')$$ hence $$(y'+1)^2(y'')^2=12(27(x+y)^2)=12(y'+1)^3$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you so much, I well be try now.